# Tool to extract SQL definition from a Paradox table

Tags: delphi, bde

actually i am working migrating a very old system which use the BDE with paradox tables, i need a tool to extract the SQL definition (CREATE TABLE .....) for the tables . i found this link [`Table-To-SQL Component for the BDE`](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20868) but the links to the library are broken, do you know any library or freeware tool to get this info?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find more tools at [torry.net -> Database Tools](http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=1442), including the above library.